# Sending form with nodejs request fails

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

I need to send form on page to change couple of fields. I use node js and *request*, *cheerio* for that:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const LOGIN_PAGE = 'http://some.url/login';
const LOGIN = 'login';
const PASSWORD = 'password';
const PAGE = 'http://some.url/admin/page/update/1';
const VAR_1 = 2;
const VAR_2 = 1;

let jar = request.jar();


function createSession(callback) {
    let params = {
        url: LOGIN_PAGE,
        jar: jar,
    };

    request(params, function(err, res, body) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('form input[name="login"]').val(LOGIN);
        $('form input[name="password"]').val(PASSWORD);

        let params = {
            url: LOGIN_PAGE,
            method: 'POST',
            form: $('form').serialize(),
            jar: jar,
        };

        request(params, function() {
            return callback();
        });
    });
}

function sendForm() {
    let params = {
        url: PAGE,
        jar: jar,
    };

    request(params, function(err, res, body) {
        let $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $('form select[name="Data[var_1]"]').val(VAR_1);
        $('form input[name="Data[var_2]"]').val(VAR_2);

        let params = {
            url: $('form').attr('action'),
            method: 'POST',
            form: $('form').serialize(),
            jar: jar,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('form input[name="_token"]').val(),
            }
        };

        request(params, function(err, res, body) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(body);
            console.log($('form').serializeArray());
        });
    });
}


createSession(sendForm);
```

Session is created perfectly and I can access protected page. Form fields are changed well too. But Answer does not contain updated data. Loaded result is the same as before (action URL is actually the same so the answer looks like I send usual GET request before).

I tried to send form as *form*, *body*, *formData*, extended headers with additional fields that can be seen in browser with no results.

Login is successful with the same approach, but update form is not. What's wrong with this sending?

Unfortunately I do not have access to the server side to debug it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple, but unexpected for me. It turned out that form is not sent with submit action, but with ajax request. So successful POST has in header:

```
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Server probably process this form only if it was sent as ajax, also in fact the whole page is reloaded.